# Add Special Charachter in SSIS Flat File Column Header

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, flat-file

I am generating a Flat file from OLEDB Source using SSIS. I have specified column headers and mapped them with source columns but SSIS automatically remove special character like '/' from column Header. How can I enforce SSIS to not remove any special character from the header? Is there any way to generate a file having a special character in column name or SSIS not allowed it?

Comment: please add some more details ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add special characters to Flat File Header as the following:

- Add a flat file connection manager
- At the flat file connection manager editor, Go to advanced Tab and rename your column

**Remark:** these special characters will be ignored when using SSIS objects like *Script Component*

[image: Flat File COnnection Manager]