# SSIS strips periods off column names in Flat File Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, flat-file, flatfiledestination

This question is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766513/how-to-return-t-sql-query-with-column-names-as-first-row) but is different in focus, so I'm creating a new question. I have a CSV file that has only column names in it, no data. I've created a Flat File Connection Manager in SSIS using Visual Studio 2012. I've checked **Column Names in the first data row** in the Connection Manager. Two column names must end in periods (Employee No., and Hrs.). Those columns are present with the periods in my CSV file. Comma, not period, is the delimiter in the Flat File Connection Manager. However, when I point the Connection Manager to the CSV file and click on Columns in the Connection Manager, the periods are replaced by spaces. Further, if I create a Flat File Destination, point it to my Flat File Connection Manager and run my SSIS package, the column names have spaces instead of periods. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this a problem if the columns don't show the periods in the data flow if it still works? You've not said it fails, so I assume it doesn't, so I don't actually see a problem here apart from not seeing the periods; and if the tool is consistent I don't see a problem again. Plus, I doubt your destination has a `.` in its name, as having object names with them in makes for confusing code.

Comment: Having the periods in the column names is a client requirement.

Comment: Seeing it the Data flow is a client requirement? That would be like a client dictating that you name your variables after stellar objects, regardless of what they're to do with. What they are called in the data flow  , provided they are meaningful, is what really matters. If the source and destination have the periods, why does the middle of the data flow matter? That's the part they'll never see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Flat File connection manager, Go To Advanced Tab and change to columns names *(Add periods instead of spaces)*

[image]

**Similar question**

- [Add Special Charachter in SSIS Flat File Column Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638348/add-special-charachter-in-ssis-flat-file-column-header)